# Finding a path in which the difference between min edge cost and max edge cost is minimum across all routes

Tags: algorithm, graph

We have to find the route from a source to a sink in a graph in which the difference between the maximum costing edge and the minimum costing edge is minimum.

I tried using a recursive solution but it would fail in condition of cycles and a modified dijkstra which also failed.

Is there an algorithm where i will not have to find all routes and then find the minimum?

Comment: When you say "failed" you mean didn't produce the correct solution? Inuitively, it seems like you'll have to examine all routes from source to sink: if you don't how can you tell that a some other route doesn't meet the conditions better, unless you already know something about all the edges in the graph

Comment: yes it didnt seem to give the right ans.

Comment: but all routes will be something of complexity 2^n which would be too slow

Comment: Where 'n' is the number of verteces?  So it is a dense graph, where every vertex is connected to every other vertex?

Comment: The constraints of the problem were 
vertices = 2000
edges = 4000

Comment: Guess the min edge cost and look for optimal substructure.

Comment: @David Eisenstat: can you provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the edges by weight (in non-decreasing order), then for each edge do the next: Add the next edges (the ones with greater or equal weight in non-decreasing order) until the source and sink are connected, then update your answer with de difference between the last edge, like this:

```
    ans = INFINITE
    for each Edge e1 in E (sorted by weight in non-decreasing order)
        clear the temporal graph
        for each Edge e2 in E
            if e2.weight >= e1.weight  
                add e2 to the temporal graph
                if sink and source are connected in the temporal graph
                    ans = min(ans, e2.weight - e1.weight)
                    break
    print ans
```

If you use the UNION-FIND structure to add edges and check connectivity between source and sink you should get an overall time of O(edges^2)

Comment: You could perhaps do even better than `O(edges^2)` by treating the problem like a "sliding window" one and using a graph data structure that tells you if deleting an edge will disconnect the graph (like in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/is-there-an-online-algorithm-to-keep-track-of-components-in-a-changing-undirecte )

Comment: @KevinWang it's been a while now since the last time I competed lol, but I gave it a little thought and I think you are right (Y), sliding window would work, I think you would need a structure that lets you check for source-sink connectivity and also lets you add and delete edges. Please correct me if I am wrong (Y)

Answer (score -1):

OK, so you have a graph, and you need to find a path from one node (source) to another (sink) such that max edge weight on the path minus min edge weight on the path is minimized. You don't say whether your graph is directed, can have negative edge weights, or has cycles, so lets assume a "yes" answer to all these questions.

When computing your path "score" (maximum difference between edge weights), we observe these are similar to path distances: you could have a path from A to B that scores higher (undesirable) or lower (desirable). If we treat path scores like path weights we observe that as we build a path by adding new edges, the path score (=weight) can only increase: given a path A->B->C where weight(A->B)=1 and weight(B->C)=5, yielding a path score of 4, if I add edge C->D to the path A->B->C, the path score can only increase or stay the same: the difference between minimum edge weight and maximum edge weight will not be lower than 4.

The conclusion from all of this is that we can explore the graph looking for best paths as if we are looking for optimal path in a graph with no negative edges. However, there could be (and likely to be, given the connectivity described) cycles. This means that [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), properly implemented, will have optimal performance relative to this graph's topology given what we know today.

#### No solution without full graph exploration

One may be misled into thinking that we can make locally good decisions about which edge should belong to the optimal path without exploring the whole graph. The following subgraph illustrates the problem with this:

[image]

Say you've need a path from A to F, and you are at node B. Given everything you know, you'd choose a path to C, as it minimizes the path score. What you don't know (yet) is that the next edge in that path will cause the score of this path to increase substantially. If you knew that you would have chosen the edge B->D as a next element in an optimal path.